# How to fill the masks?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv, python

I wish to fill the hollow masks in the below binary image. I tried finding contours to fill but didn't work.
[image: Mask Image]

Can someone give me some pointers on How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you found the contours, they you can just fill the convex poly.

`cv2.fillConvexPoly(binary_image, np.array(rect['boundary'], 'int32'), 255)`

You will have to adjust this line to work with your own code, but just pass it an index to the contour that you want to fill, and it will fill it with your desired color.

Comment: The contours from `drawContours` were poor. It is due to opening in the masks. Also, I tried combinations of dilate and erode morphological process but it didn't work.